# Количество цитируемых вопросов по метке

Tags: дефект, предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, метки

При просмотре [цитируемых](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2B%2B?sort=frequent&pageSize=30) вопросов по метке справа видно следующий блок:

[image: кол-во цитирований]

Считаю, что слово "количество" тут явно лишнее и его надо убрать. В других вкладках ничего подобного нет, например ([без ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2B%2B?sort=unanswered&pageSize=30)):

[image: без ответа]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавил [предложение](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40267622?key=0b8c44bb5c5964ca9db4b050d6e53332) на transifex:

- one:

  > часто упоминаемый вопрос по метке
- few:

  > часто упоминаемых вопроса по метке
- many

  > часто упоминаемых вопросов по метке